# Overlay поверх картинки

Tags: вёрстка, css

Есть картинки [такого вида](http://jsfiddle.net/6WVfz/2/).

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.thumbnails').cycle();
});
```

```css
.thumbnails a img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.cycle2.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>

<div class="thumbnails" data-cycle-fx="carousel" data-cycle-timeout="2000" data-cycle-slides="> a" data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true">
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://people.mozilla.org/~faaborg/files/shiretoko/firefoxIcon/firefox-128.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/Compass_Icon.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/google/chrome/256/Google-Chrome-icon.png" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Нужно каким-то образом разместить слой определенного цвета (и прозрачности) поверх каждой, не меняя параметров отображения родительского элемента (position, display). Почему не меняя? Дело в том, что в safari анимация в этом случае выгладит ужасно. Как сделать?

PS: обновил пример, но суть та же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы примерно о таком?
http://jsfiddle.net/bAcg9/2/

```css
.thumb {
    position: static; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    z-index: 99;
}
.thumb:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: rgba(200,127,127,.5);
    margin: 0 0 0 -500px;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="thumb">
    <img src="http://macovod.com.ua/media/uploads/2011/11/safari-icon.jpg" alt="">    
</a>
```

Comment: margin уже пробовал, к сожалению, не подойдет

Comment: ну тогда так: http://jsfiddle.net/bAcg9/3/

Кстати, а почему не подойдёт маргин?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bAcg9/4/ — а так маргин можно использовать?

Comment: можно, конечно, всех обмануть и сделать так: http://jsfiddle.net/bAcg9/5/

Comment: > можно, конечно, всех обмануть и сделать так:

Для меня способ новый, но все равно не подходит. Я, наверное, не с того начал, более конкретный пример: http://jsfiddle.net/6WVfz/2/

Comment: стало понятно насчёт маргина, но вот этот способ: http://jsfiddle.net/6WVfz/5/ — работает исправно, в том числе и в сафари (у меня 6.1 на os 10.8)

Comment: У меня тоже работает исправно в сафари. Как оказалось анимация отображалась криво из-за того, что у меня на странице выше есть еще одна карусель и они конфликтуют друг с другом. Сейчас разбираюсь почему, но это уже вопрос другой темы.